# Python 3 Combobox issue?

Tags: combobox, tkinter, python-3.4

I am stuck with middle of the development, Need some help to resolve this. I want to add the Combobox to my interface and selection should come from text file.Text file have all the list of items. I want to put text file list to combobox and after select and click ok, should run with  shell script. My code as below.

```html
__author__ = 'shanaka'
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import subprocess
import os
from tkinter import messagebox
import Pmw
from tkinter import tix

################Options
def sel():
#   selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
   if str(var.get()) == '1':
       label.config(text= 'Windows is not supporting yet')
   if str(var.get())== '2':
       label.config(text = 'Linux is supporting')

####
def helloCallBack():
   messagebox.showinfo( "Hello Python", "Hello World")

#######
def handle_selection():
    print("You've selected: " + var1.get())

#################


root = Tk()
root.title("Volatility")
root.geometry("600x300")

#########OS Selection GUI
var = IntVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Windows", variable=var, value=1,command=sel)
R1.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky=W )

R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Linux", variable=var, value=2,command=sel)
#R2.pack( anchor = W )
R2.grid( row=1, column=0, sticky=W )
label = Label(root)
label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

#########

########Get Dump GUI
DumpButton = Button(root, text ="Create Memory Dump", command = helloCallBack)
DumpButton.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
###############
######Copy Dump
CopyButton = Button(root, text ="Copy Dump to analyis directory", command = helloCallBack)
CopyButton.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
#############################
########Cobobox



with open('Plugins') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
#    options = OptionMenu(root,var1,*lines)
    options = Pmw.Combobox(root,label_text='Plugins',scrolledlist_items=[*lines])
    options.grid(row=5, column=0,sticky=W)
    options.selectitem(lines[1])
#    var1.set(lines[1])


b = Button(root,text="Select", command = handle_selection , width=10)
b.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=W)




root.mainloop()
```

But giving below error.

> line 73
>       options = Pmw.Combobox(root,label_text='Plugins',scrolledlist_items=[*lines])
>                                                                               ^
>   SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
>
> Still no luck :(, error as below- Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/shanaka/PycharmProjects/volatility/main2.py", line 73, in  options = Pmw.ComboBox(root,label_text='Plugins',scrolledlist_items=lines) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Pmw/Pmw_2_0_0/lib/PmwComboBox.py", line 147, in init self.initialiseoptions() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Pmw/Pmw_2_0_0/lib/PmwBase.py", line 599, in initialiseoptions '" for ' + self.**class**.**name**) TypeError: descriptor 'join' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list' –

Comment: The error message I  clear; you can't unpack a sequence into a list literal like that. Given that `lines` is already a list, why were you trying to do that in the first place?!

Comment: i just want to get items in file to menu, As example- file contain below texts.
a
b
C

so i want to get those to combobox as drop down menu.
when i select "a" and press select button, then it will execute the command on shell, that is what i want to do, Can you tell me any other way to do this.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question - why not just `scrolledlist_items=lines`?

Comment: Still the error is coming friend,

options = Pmw.Combobox(root,label_text='Plugins',scrolledlist_items=lines)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Pmw/Pmw_2_0_0/lib/PmwLoader.py", line 171, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: Combobox

Comment: That's because you're spelling [`ComboBox`](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/ComboBox.html) wrongly; Python is **case-sensitive**.

Comment: Well that's a profoundly unhelpful "error report". Whitespace *is part of Python's syntax*, it's unreadable in comments. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and **edit the question**, or delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the Support I found the solution , I used ttk.ComboBox, rather using Pmw. Thank you Jonrsharp `option = ttk.Combobox(root,state="readonly",values=(lines))`